# I can not access the previous page when i go to tabs page

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a starter in ionic when I go to "app.org.all" from "app.home" there is no back button in the page.

https://plnkr.co/edit/muHqqOLr8G1v1NFW9QL6?p=preview

this route code :

```
.state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'

        })

        //Home
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

 .state('app.org', {
            url: '/org',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/org/list.html',
                    controller: 'orgCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.org.all', {
            url: '/all',
            views: {
                'profileContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/org/list.all.html',
                    controller: 'org2Ctrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

who allow backing when I go to the page has tabs?

Comment: Have you included  ` <ion-nav-buttons side="left" > </ion-nav-buttons>` ?

Comment: can you paste your code so that i will try to fix it

Comment: can you show me html tab page.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/muHqqOLr8G1v1NFW9QL6?p=preview